# Unable to create/ delete file/folder on Linux Fedora when getting call from php server

Tags: php, linux, fedora

```
-Tried
```

-  sudo chmod -R a+rwx /usr/share/nginx/uploadedData

- sudo chmod -R 0777 /usr/share/nginx/uploadedData
- stat /usr/share/nginx/uploadedData

  [root@localhost uploadedData]# stat /usr/share/nginx/uploadedData  File: ‘/usr/share/nginx/uploadedData’
        Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
      Device: fd02h/64770d    Inode: 528513      Links: 2
      Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  asingh)   Gid: ( 1000/  asingh)
      Context: unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0
      Access: 2014-11-10 16:38:44.723660912 +0530
      Modify: 2014-11-10 20:32:33.076960484 +0530
      Change: 2014-11-10 16:38:44.723660912 +0530
       Birth: -

  // But still my PHP code

  ```
  $file_pathDecoded='/usr/share/nginx/uplodedData';
  $filename=$file_pathDecoded.'/test.txt';
  if (is_file($filename)) {

     chmod($filename, 0777);

     if (unlink($filename)) {
        echo 'File deleted';
     } else {
        echo 'Cannot remove that file';//results this
     }

  } else {
    echo 'File does not exist';
  }

  if (!mkdir($file_pathDecoded.'/newfolder', 0777, TRUE)) {
      echo('Failed to create folders...');//results this
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
$file_pathDecoded='/usr/share/nginx/uplodedData';
$file_pathDecoded=base64_decode($file_path);
```

so you see the error?
your variable $file_path in line 2 is undefined.

and pls try chown the file to the WWW user.
PHP safe_mode requires the file being owned by the same user the script is run by.
your file is owned by UID 1000, which doesn't seem to be the web user.

Comment: Second line is removed and it still give me same error.

Comment: you have to chown the file to the www user.

Comment: echo posix_getuid(); echo('::');echo `whoami`;  echo('::');......Results in ..48::apache ::Array ( [name] => apache [passwd] => x [uid] => 48 [gid] => 48 [gecos] => Apache [dir] => /usr/share/httpd [shell] => /sbin/nologin )

Comment: and I am running php server + nginx server as a root user, where folder stat is given below.

Comment: [asingh@localhost ~]$ stat /usr/share/nginx/uploadedData/
  File: ‘/usr/share/nginx/uploadedData/’
  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd01h/64769d Inode: 528513      Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: ( 1000/  asingh)   Gid: ( 1000/  asingh)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0
Access: 2014-11-14 11:09:40.759777139 +0530
Modify: 2014-11-10 16:42:24.904640044 +0530
Change: 2014-11-14 11:10:16.492773753 +0530
 Birth: -

Comment: well, your stat cmd clearly says, that this file is owned by user asingh, group asingh. this is not the webserver user. in addition, i doubt that nginx runs as root. even if you start it as root, it will downgrade its permissions to a normal user, typically called nginx. you can verify it by ls -l the logfile or the pidfile of nginx, typically ls -l /var/run/nginx.pid . next thing is, you seem to use /usr/share/nginx/ as working directory. this is a system folder of nginx, you are strongly encouraged to use a folder like /var/www/ or /srv/www , that is created for that purpose.

Comment: /usr/share/nginx is created by me, and new stat is as [root@localhost asingh]# stat /usr/share/nginx/uploadedData/  File: ‘/usr/share/nginx/uploadedData/’
  Size: 4096       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: fd01h/64769d Inode: 528513      Links: 2
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (   48/  apache)   Gid: (   48/  apache)
Context: unconfined_u:object_r:usr_t:s0
Access: 2014-11-19 02:43:43.422931816 +0530
Modify: 2014-11-19 01:48:19.347128336 +0530
Change: 2014-11-19 02:43:43.422931816 +0530
 Birth: ---
Yes Nginx is working as root user,)But now also its not working

Comment: nginx.pid have 2399. only 2399 is written in this file

Comment: the content of this file is not important, but with ls -l you will get the owner of the file, and this is the user of the nginx process. for unlink read this: php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php The php-file needs to have the same owner as the file you want to delete and the folder it resides in. chown these files/folder to the owner of the nginx.pid file. then add /usr/share/nginx/uploadedData/ to the open_basedir config value in php.ini and restart webserver.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code on line 2 should be like this

> $file_pathDecoded=base64_decode($file_pathDecoded);